# Specifying a parameter in C#'s OrderBy methods

Tags: c#

Good morning,

Let's imagine I have a list of Tuple elements, and a function taking a String and returning a Double, for example. How can I, from some other method, use the list's `OrderBy` method with that function calculated only on the first coordinate of each tuple? For example, `return List.OrderBy(FunctionTakingString(Tuple'sFirstCoordinate)).First` ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do:

```
return list.OrderBy(x => CustomFunction(x.Item1))
           .First();
```

`OrderBy` just needs to be provided with a delegate to compute a value from an element. Within the delegate you can do what you want, within reason.